# Why the links in the lower third of the buttons don't work?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, href

I have a pure CSS Dropdown button and would like to keep it without JS.

However, I have the following problem; as soon as I click on the bottom third of one of the button links, only the Dropdown menu closes but the link is not opening. The links only work from the beginning of the text (up from the bottom). Everything below the text is not clickable or does not open the link. Everything above the beginning of the text is working fine. I hope I have described my problem understandably enough.

So my question is of course: where is my error or what do I have to fix in my code so that the entire surface of the buttons become clickable links?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}
/* Dropdown container start */
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

/* button */
.dropbtn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #121212;
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

/* Dropdown content */
.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  width: 130px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/* show Dropdown content */
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
  outline: none;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropdown:focus .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: black;
  border: 1.5px solid #f0f0f0;
}

/* mask to close menu by clicking on the button */
.dropdown .db2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:focus .db2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My example Website</h1>
<div class="dropdown" tabindex="1" title="Open the main menu">
  <div class="db2" tabindex="1"></div>
  <a class="dropbtn">My menu</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a>
  <a href="random-en.html">Link 2</a>
  <a href="3d-en.html">Link 3</a>
  <a href="info-en.html">Link 4</a>
  <a href="c_en/hashtag.html">Link 5</a>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me as well, if I understand your question; what browser are you using?  Does it not work for you in the snippet you have added to the question?

Comment: @Ouroborus As soon as I click the text, it is working. Also above the text it is working, but the bottom edge is not a link somehow, it only closes the dropdown menu when I click the bottom edge of the buttons. I tested it in Chrome and Firefox and both browsers have the problem.

Comment: "The bottom edge of the buttons"... you mean the space between the anchors caused by the margin you put in there? Yeah, if you click on a place that isn't an anchor, it won't register a click on the anchor.

Comment: I get the same result as KiBLS.  It's not padding or margin, or the height of the dropdown-content

Comment: @Heretic - You can make the margin-top and padding 0 and it still happens.  And I have seen it on my own code too.  It's in my todo list.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ae5qoy4g/ No margin, no problem. Could be hidden characters in the HTML, because I tidied the snippet before copying... @RohitGupta

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Well for me the same problem still occurs (so also in your jsfiddle example). The lower part of the buttons still does not respond to my clicks. It is like RohitGupta says; the issue remains even with no margin.... :/

Comment: What is the `db2` div for? It takes up the entire viewport and essentially covers everything.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey The db2 div is basically for collapsing. If you remove some CSS elements from it (like top, left or anything else), collapsing by click will not work anymore. So it is meant for closing the div by click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have now my final CSS Dropdown solution that seem to work for me. I get inspired by this website https://lage.us/CSS-Onclick-Dropdown-Menu.html and its very slim code.

Thanks anyway to everyone who helped and gave some thought to the problem.

```css
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}


/*start of the dropdown container*/

.menutop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 1px;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.menutop:hover {
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: black;
}


/*labeling of the left button*/

.menutop::before {
  content: "\2630 \a0 Menu";
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.menutop:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*If :focus detected the dropdown menu is displayed by making it visible*/

.menutop:focus .menutop-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}


/*style for the dropdown box*/

.menutop-dropdown {
  background: transparent;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 6px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 1s;
}


/*style the links in the dropdown*/

.menutop-dropdown a {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 6px 0 0 -12px;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.menutop-dropdown a:hover {
  background: #121212;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>My example Website</h1>

<div tabindex="0" class="menutop">
  <div class="menutop-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a>
    <a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a solution but it is only working inside the snippet, as soon as i integrate it into my website, the style is messed up because of the missing position i think so... :/

I have deleted the following values from my CSS:

```css
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {transform:translateY(20px);}
.dropdown {position:relative;}
```

And replaced the following Values

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-content {position:absolute; top:50%;}
```

With these values

```css
.dropdown .dropdown-content {position:relative; margin-top:12px;}
```

As you can see in my new code, you can now click wherever you want and the link will work as it should work.

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}
/* Dropdown container start */
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

/* button */
.dropbtn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #121212;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

/* Dropdown content */
.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/* show Dropdown content */
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
  outline: none;

  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropdown:focus .dropbtn {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: black;
  border: 1.5px solid #f0f0f0;
}

/* mask to close menu by clicking on the button */
.dropdown .db2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:focus .db2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My example Website</h1>
<div class="dropdown" tabindex="1" title="Open the main menu">
  <div class="db2" tabindex="1"></div>
  <a class="dropbtn">My menu</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Focus is lost in 0.25 sec while it needs a longer time for click work.
I updated the transition time to 1 sec.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 21px;
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        max-width: 550px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: black;
      }
      h1 {
        color: white;
      }
      /* Dropdown container start */
      .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
      }

      /* button */
      .dropbtn {
        padding: 8px 12px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #121212;
        border: 1.5px solid white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.25s ease-out;
      }

      /* Dropdown content */
      .dropdown-content {
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 3px;
        z-index: 9999;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 1s ease-out;
      }
      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.25s ease-out;
        width: 130px;
      }
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
      }

      /* show Dropdown content */
      .dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
        outline: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0.25s ease-out;
      }

      .dropbtn:hover,
      .dropdown:focus .dropbtn {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        color: black;
        border: 1.5px solid #f0f0f0;
      }

      /* mask to close menu by clicking on the button */
      .dropdown .db2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
      }
      .dropdown:focus .db2 {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My example Website</h1>
    <div class="dropdown" tabindex="1" title="Open the main menu">
      <div class="db2" tabindex="1"></div>
      <a class="dropbtn">My menu</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="random-e.html" target="_blank">Link 1</a>
        <a href="random-en.html">Link 2</a>
        <a href="3d-en.html">Link 3</a>
        <a href="info-en.html">Link 4</a>
        <a href="c_en/hashtag.html">Link 5</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions. The links are irrelevant. They just need to navigate. Where they navigate doesn't matter, even if they navigate to error pages.

Comment: I have the same problem here. It's not because of the links. The links are working fine but as soon as I click the bottom of a button-link, it doesn't redirect me but only closes the dropdown. Could it really be because of my browsers or do you not click at the bottom to test the issue?

Comment: I clicked the button and it was working well.

Comment: @tech But did you click the bottom edge of the button and did it work there? Could it be the operating system? I use Ubuntu with Firefox and Chrome... maybe the whole thing behaves differently on a Mac or a Windows PC? What are you using? Because even in the conversation above, one party can reproduce the problem and another party apparently can not... very curious...

Comment: I will check bottom edge.

Comment: It is due to transform: translateY(20px);
For instance, in case of transform: translateY(20px); , button click never works
I will update the answer soon.

Comment: @tech Yes, it seems like we are getting close to the solution. If I take out the translateY(20px) value and increase .dropdown .dropdown-content {top: 135%;}, the buttons are working. However, the problem remains with the top menu button. So the lower buttons work that way but the top one (I mean "My menu") still has the same problem somehow... Ok, I will wait for your solution now. Maybe you will get it right :)

Comment: @tech Ok, with your help it is almost solved now... I removed the translateY(20px) completely and then just changed the values from: .dropdown .dropdown-content {top: 135%;position:absolute} INTO .dropdown .dropdown-content {margin-top: 12px;position:relative} and now (almost) everything works... but now I have another issue with the upper part of the main menu button. The lower buttons are working as expected but the main menu button has now issues on the top edge where the other buttons had the issue on the lower edge...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246600/discussion-between-tech-and-kibls).